# clicking a specific jsx element in an array of JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components, rendering, jsx

i have a function which returns an array of div's, each div has a click event associated with it, and the array is created by the for loop.

what i want to do is i have to click a div and open another component.

i have created an onCLick function on each div and inside that function i am setting the state for rendering of that component(which i want to open on click of a div).

what i am facing is if i click on a div all the component are opening.

what should i do to open only component for only that div which i clicked.

thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an example of your current code?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: hey guyes  thankyou for your response but i kind of solved that issue, here is the link where i found the hint .

[link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zl6wlk253?codemirror=1)